# Sort Products REST API : Magento 2

Tags: magento2, api, rest-api

I did a sort for product by price through API:

> http://domain.com/index.php/rest/V1/search?searchCriteria[requestName]=quick_search_container&searchCriteria[filterGroups][0][filters][0][field]=search_term&searchCriteria[filterGroups][0][filters][0][value]=%25life%25&searchCritseria[sortOrders][1][field]=price&searchCriteria[sortOrders][1][direction]=DESC&searchCriteria[currentPage]=1&searchCriteria[pageSize]=100

But there is no sort any help?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you should try to set index to zero after `sortOrders`

eg:
`http://domain.com/index.php/rest/V1/products?searchCriteria[page_size]=10&searchCriteria[sortOrders][0][field]=price&searchCriteria[sortOrders][0][direction]=DESC`

Answer (score 0):

In URL you have passed wrong `searchCritseria` spelling, Replace it with `searchCriteria` and it should work.

[http://domain.com/index.php/rest/V1/search?searchCriteria[requestName]=quick_search_container&searchCriteria[filterGroups][0][filters][0][field]=search_term&searchCriteria[filterGroups][0][filters][0][value]=%25life%25&searchCriteria[sortOrders][1][field]=price&searchCriteria[sortOrders][1][direction]=DESC&searchCriteria[currentPage]=1&searchCriteria[pageSize]=100](http://domain.com/index.php/rest/V1/search?searchCriteria%5BrequestName%5D=quick_search_container&searchCriteria%5BfilterGroups%5D%5B0%5D%5Bfilters%5D%5B0%5D%5Bfield%5D=search_term&searchCriteria%5BfilterGroups%5D%5B0%5D%5Bfilters%5D%5B0%5D%5Bvalue%5D=%25life%25&searchCriteria%5BsortOrders%5D%5B1%5D%5Bfield%5D=price&searchCriteria%5BsortOrders%5D%5B1%5D%5Bdirection%5D=DESC&searchCriteria%5BcurrentPage%5D=1&searchCriteria%5BpageSize%5D=100)